# Calling Sort on Main Against Different Child Class Value

Tags: c++

I have this Parent Class call

```
Shape (ShapeTwoD.cpp)
```

He got 2 Child Class

```
1 is Rectangle (Rectangle.cpp)
1 is Square (Square.cpp)
```

There this variable call area declare at Rectangle & Square , but not at Shape(the parent)

So i was trying to sort by area ascending, however area can be access by

```
class->getArea();


vector<ShapeTwoD*> myVector;
```

//during the period of recording data like width ,height to the shape.

```
myVector[arrayCount] = new Rectangle();
myVector[arrayCount].setWidth(inWidth);
myVector[arrayCount].setHeight(inHeight);
myVector[arrayCount].computeArea();
```

arrayCount ++;

```
//done record width , height and then compute area of the shape
```

Assuming myVector now Contains about 2 Rectangle and 1 Square

Now I want to sort them by area ascending.

But my getArea() function is only available at child class.

If i try do this

```
sort(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(),funcAreaSort);
```

I not sure where to create funcAreaSort , next is how do i send in child area , assuming if they are same shape class(rectangle against rectangle) or different shape class (rectangle against shape)

how i create a boolean operator overload that can compare by getArea() then see which is better return a.getArea() > b.getArea() and sort myVector

Question is Where do i create those function I was thinking of making it a free method at main.cpp but i fail getting the thing sort and compile with error like qualifier error

```
error: passing 'const shapeTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double shapeTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.
error: passing 'const shapeTwoD' as 'this' argument of 'virtual double shapeTwoD::getArea()' discards qualifers.
```

Comment: It is hard to make sense out of your post, but the error is probably telling you that `getArea()` needs to be a `const` method. The error is also incompatible with what you are saying.

Comment: How does `myVector.computeArea();` even compile? Is that an `std::vector`? If so, it doesn't have a `computeArea` method...

Comment: @Lirik, i just put computeArea as its a function under child and i running it to setArea . the purpose was to show there is some area in the myVector[arrayCount]

Comment: @juanchopanza where should i put const for getArea in ShapeTwoD , is it virtual double getArea const for declaration and for constructor is virtual double ShapeTwoD::getArea() const {  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make the compare function take `ShapeTwoD*` as parameters, and have a `virtual` `getArea` method in the base class, which you override in the children.

2) Make the method `getArea` `const`:

```
int getArea() const;
```

because it logically makes sense & so that you can call it on `const` objects.

Comment: i did try to make getArea() double, but how should my compareArea function be coded like. will be great to have more information. Tried for several hours but still unable get the sort done.